# How to make content go under the header while scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the content not going under the fixed header while I'm scrolling.
I already tried using top-padding in the body equal to the headers height but it doesn't work. I looked for an answer all over and everything I try doesn't work. Maybe you guys can help me out by looking at my HTML and CSS.

```css
body { 
    text-align: center; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    background-color:hsl(0, 100%, 71%);
}

#header { 
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 97%); 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 300px); 
    grid-template-areas: 'img name navbar'; 
    height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<header style="position:fixed; top:0;width:100%;" id="header">
```

Here is a link to the page: https://codepen.io/code7722/pen/PoNZaKR.

Comment: z-index:99999 add this in the header.

Comment: Typo in `"position:reltive;`

Comment: Add z-index: 999; to #header selector in CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change what stacking order content renders in, you want to set a [z-index value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)! Add this to your #header styles: `z-index: 100;`

Comment: incomplete awnser. z-index aloen will not do the trick. The other divs need a margin-top equal or greater of the headers height. otherwise the content will be cut away.

Comment: @tacoshy The question was about how to get the content to go under the header, not get cut off. From the question, they already fixed that issue with the margin/padding to make up for the initial header position

Comment: no they didnt had a margin yet. as they where not able to get the conent go beanather the header they will need to add the amrgin as otherwise they will face the next problem. Problem solution is not to fix a problem and creating a new problem at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html { 
  text-align: center; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
  background-color:hsl(0, 100%, 71%);
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

#header { 
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 97%); 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 145px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

use z-index and position:fixed.

Also dont!!! mix Style into HTML when you have a CSS file.
Styling like font style and backgroudn color should go into HTML not Body class.